# ¿Cómo puedo detener la generación de los números aleatorios cuando un número se repita?

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy realizando un programa en java de forma visual, del algoritmo de productos medios (simulación), Ya genera los números aleatorios de forma adecuada, sin embargo tengo un problema al detener el proceso cuando un número se repita. Ya he intentado hacerlo con dos for al final y con un while. El arreglo ui es el arreglo que contiene los números aleatorios generados, xi es el arreglo que contiene los valores del número que se le concatena "0." y el arreglo iteración es contiene la posición del número aleatorio

```
//Variables que utilizo, declaradas de forma global
    int x0 = 0, x1 = 0, multiplicacion = 0, tam_x0 = 0, num = 0, cantidad_numeros = 0;
String multi_texto ="";
String[] xi = new String[1000];
Double[] ui = new Double[1000];
Integer[] iteracion = new Integer[1000];
String[] titulos = new String[] {"i", "xi", "ui"}; //Tabla
DefaultTableModel table = new  DefaultTableModel();

//Método que genera los números aleatorios
  void NumerosAleatorios (int x0, int x1, int tam){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { //For1 crea los números aleatorios
            multiplicacion = x0 * x1; //Se realiza la multiplicacion
            multi_texto = multiplicacion + ""; //Se converte la multiplcacion a String
            if (multi_texto.length() == tam) { //Secomprueba que la multiplicacion tenga el tamaño 2n
                
                iteracion[i] = i + 1; //Se llena el arreglo de las posiciones
                num = Integer.parseInt(multi_texto.substring(2, 6)); //Se le quitan las cifras correspondientes al numero
                xi[i] = multi_texto.substring(2, 6);  //Se almacena el valor de xi
                multi_texto = "0." + multi_texto.substring(2, 6); //Se convierte el valor de xi a decimal
                ui[i] = Double.parseDouble(multi_texto); //Se almacena el número en el arreglo
                
                x0 = x1; //Se cambia el valor de la variable x0 por x1
                x1 = num; //Se cambia el valor de x1 por el de numero que se convierte a decimal
                cantidad_numeros++; //Contador de cantidad de numeros generados
                
            } else { //Si la cadena no tiene la cantidad de numeros correspondientes
                                
                for (int j = 0; j < (tam - multi_texto.length()); j++) { //Este for permite que se agreguen 0's hasta que se tenga la logitud de 4n
                    multi_texto = 0+multi_texto; //Se concatenan los 0  a la cadena
                }
                iteracion[i] = i + 1; //Se llena el arreglo de las posiciones
                num = Integer.parseInt(multi_texto.substring(2, 6)); //Se le quitan las cifras correspondientes al numero
                xi[i] = multi_texto.substring(2, 6);  //Se almacena el valor de xi
                multi_texto = "0." + multi_texto.substring(2, 6); //Se convierte el valor de xi a decimal
                ui[i] = Double.parseDouble(multi_texto); //Se almacena el número en el arreglo
                
                x0 = x1; //Se cambia el valor de la variable x0 por x1
                x1 = num; //Se cambia el valor de x1 por el de numero que se convierte a decimal
                cantidad_numeros++; //Contador de cantidad de numeros generados
                
            }
        } //Termina for1
        
        txt_TotalNum.setText(cantidad_numeros+"");
        
        //For que permite el llenado de la tabla
        for (int k = 0; k < ui.length; k++) {
            table.addRow(new Object[] {iteracion[k], xi[k], ui[k]
                    }); //se manda a la tabla cada uno de los elementos i, xi, ui o numero aleatorio
        }
        
        //For que muestra los valores de los arreglos y el numero de iteracion
        for (int j = 0; j < ui.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(( j + 1) +", x" + (j + 1) + "= " + xi[j]+", u"+ (j+1) + "= " + ui[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Ya haz probando usando la técnica de memorización?

Comment: No, nunca he trabajado con esa técnica

Comment: ¿Y por qué no la intentas? Lobos ya te puso una implementación algo precaria pero efectiva para que te des una idea

Comment: De hecho, la estoy realizando

Comment: Otra opción sería usar un generador que te permitiera obtener un sendero hamiltoniano

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pueden guardar los número generados en un `Map` y consultarlo para saber si el número generado ya ha sido generado antes.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, Void> numerosGenerados = new HashMap<>();
        
        // arreglo de números por llenar
        int[] aleatorios = new int[10];
        
        int generados = 0;
        
        Random random = new Random();
        // generar aleatorios mientras no se haya llenado el arreglo 
        while (generados < aleatorios.length) {
            // obtener número aleatorio positivo
            int numero = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
            
            // si ya fue generado  continuar con otro número
            if (numerosGenerados.containsKey(numero)) continue;

            // agregar si no se ha generado antes
            numerosGenerados.put(numero, null);

            aleatorios[generados++] = numero;
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aleatorios));

    }
}
```

Comment: En este caso, ¿se puede poner una determinada cantidad de números hasta que se repita el número?

Comment: Me puedes explicar un poco más?

Comment: Es que realice tú código tal y como esta pero sólo me devolvió un número, no sé si se puede determinar la cantidad de números aleatorios a generar

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta para llenar un arreglo de números aleatorios distintos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me quedó!